# Google Ads in HTML5 Godot 4 game that is embedded Electron chromium browser and that runs on localhost http server

Tags: html5, godot-4, advertisements

Hi Google Ads shows ads on domain not localhost. But my game that is embedded in Electron browser and runs on htpp server on loaclhost (local html file). I want to show ads from localhost server. But I don't know how to do that. Don't know what html and javascript codes to insert into index.html file of the Godot 4 HTML5 game. So how can I achieve this?
Is it possible to show ads from localhost and get earnings from those ads?

Thanks.

Comment: Logic would say no since the ad publisher won't be able to confirm that the ad really was watched. You can show ads from locally (for example you have made multiple games and show advertisement for your other games - but in this case you don't expect money from them).

Comment: @Zibelas Alright, İs it possible to show a html frame that fills game canvas and that frame will show ads from the url of the advertise website of my own?